# ServiceStack deserialize json with tabulators and new lines

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I have code to read JSON content:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    return TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<Symulacja>(reader);
}
```

It works only when json file is like:

```
{Width:1,Height:1}
```

I like to have files formated:

```
{
    Width: 1
    , Height: 1
}
```

But `TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromReader` can't parse that and sets `null` in `Symulacja` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ServiceStack's JsonSerializer to serialize JSON and not [TypeSerializer which is the JSV Format](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=176):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<Symulacja>(reader);
}
```

Also the `.ToJson()` and `.FromJson<T>()` extension methods useful convenience wrappers for consuming JSON, e.g:

```
string json = dto.ToJson();
MyDto json.FromJson<MyDto>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because TypeSerializer class serializes and deserializes from a hybrid format called JSV (JSON + CSV) which is not same JSON. Read [this](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=176) post for further details.

You can use some other library like JSON.Net to deserialize your JSON data.

Comment: That's right: it's not JSON. Maybe is there some switch: Read/Write human readable file?

Comment: I didn't see a secret switch. I believe `ServiceStack.Text`'s performance heavily relies on consuming this specific format. It is still human readable, not editable though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this first try to parse your Json String here \

http://json.parser.online.fr/

if it passed there then goto http://json2csharp.com/ ... paste your string ... it will generate a Class with Attributes

then

paste the class inside your code . and create new object for the class

and call Deserialize

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var Data = DeserializeFromJson<Test>("Json String");
public T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string json)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ObjJSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    T deserializedProduct = ObjJSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    return deserializedProduct;
}
 public class Test
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```